# Config problem with Apache 2 on Win 7

Tags: apache-2.2, zend-framework, zend-server

The real problem is that I'm not terribly good with infrastructure, but you probably can't help me there.

My issues today is that I'm trying to configure a virtual server on Win 7. I'm using Zend Server, and I'm following the Zend framework introductory tutorial, http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html.

When I add the following config to the bottom of my http.conf file, I get 403 forbidden when I try to visit http://localhost/.  Here's the config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName openco.local
   DocumentRoot /ZendFW-Projects/opencoV2/public
   <Directory /ZendFW-Projects/opencoV2/public>
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas?  The tutorial says to make sure that NameVirtualHost is defined, however I wasn't sure what format this directive should take, so I left it out.  I see that other related tutorials also leave it out, so I don't think that's the problem.

I have edited my etc/hosts, of course...

Any assistance much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually do need the `NameVirtualHost` directive. You can put it at the top level of your configuration file, outside the snippet above:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

You will likely also need the `SetEnv` directive mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks justarobert.  I also had the path to my public directory wrong.  (I though it was relative to the httpdocs root).  Anyhow, all good now!