# Local Host and Virtual Host point to same location

Tags: apache-2.2, zend-server

I have recently setup a virtual host on my local web server (per this question, [Config problem with Apache 2 on Win 7](https://serverfault.com/questions/259973/config-problem-with-apache-2-on-win-7)).

I'm using Apache 2.2 on Win 7, as part of Zend Server.

At the moment, the root of my application's directory is accessible via either the virtual host (http://openco.local), or the local host name (http://localhost).  How do I change this so that openco.local continues as is, but localhost points to it's original location (i.e. htdocs)?

Any assistance appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add another virtual host definition *before* the one for openco.local, as in:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

That way open.local ceases to be the default virtual host.